SUM same column virtual result POSTGRES
SELECT (jsonb_array_elements((balance)::jsonb->'savings')->'amount')::float AS virtual_balance 
FROM accounts 
WHERE id = 58117;

Result:
virtual_balance
---------------
162.09
0.16

I need to select this result to be added together, resulting in 162.25
the expected result should look like
virtual_balance
---------------
162,25

I needed it to be in the same select without using WHEN or other loops, my database and Postgres.

Can you add an example of your json structure in your question?


To question text  add the Postgres version. 2) Also add sample data with expected output.


Put the set-returning function in a lateral table expression, then you can use SUM:
SELECT SUM((savings->'amount')::float) AS virtual_balance 
FROM accounts, jsonb_array_elements(balance::jsonb->'savings') savings
WHERE id = 58117;

or
SELECT SUM(amount) AS virtual_balance 
FROM accounts, jsonb_to_recordset(balance::jsonb->'savings') savings(amount float)
WHERE id = 58117;


You can add the decimal separator as a comma, change it to characters (if you need the numeric values you have to convert it back to float later) using to_char:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html
Query:
SELECT to_char(SUM((jsonb_array_elements((balance)::jsonb->'savings')->>'amount')::float), 'FM999999999D00') as virtual_balance FROM accounts WHERE id = 58117;

The reason for using it like this is because of the following:

The pattern characters S, L, D, and G represent the sign, currency
symbol, decimal point, and thousands separator characters defined by
the current locale (see lc_monetary and lc_numeric). The pattern
characters period and comma represent those exact characters, with the
meanings of decimal point and thousands separator, regardless of
locale.

So D is the comma instead of period (.),
Tested on PosgreSQL 16
